# Why are $W_1, W_2$ eigenspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the minimal polynomial, $m_T = (x-2)(x^2+1)$. We denote $W_1:=\ker(T-2I)$ and $W_2:=\ker(T^2+I)$. The claim is that $W_1, W_2$ are eigenspaces of $T$.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what are the eigenvalues of $T$? If $v$ is an eigenvector of $T,$ say with $Tv=\lambda v$ (pick one of your eigenvalues for $\lambda$), then is $v\in W_1$ or $W_2$? On the other hand, if $v\in W_1$ or $W_2,$ then is $v$ an eigenvector of $T$?